# XML Schema construct, xml with same element with different values need a schema

Tags: xsd

So I'm having a problem with checking attributes. I've tried everything I know so far and it hasn't worked. If perishable=no there are some extra elements, if its yes then there are some different elements from the perishable=no. I've tried groups and it hasn't worked. I was thinking to group the food and stock but there is that restriction on perishable. Only if perishable is yes we have food element and if its no we have stock element. Help please!!!

```
    <product id = "p12" perishable = "yes">
    <name>Ice cream</name>
    <manufacturer>xsz Co.</manufacturer>
    <quantity>25</quantity>
    <price>2</price>

    <food>
        <nutrition>
            <calcium>10.30</calcium>
            <proteins>35.5</proteins>
            <fat>10</fat>
        </nutrition>

        <expirationDate>2000-09-12</expirationDate>
    </food>
</product>

<product id = "p13" perishable = "no">
    <name>AA Battries</name>
    <manufacturer>DCells</manufacturer>
    <quantity>100</quantity>
    <price>4</price>

    <stock>
        <warehouse id = "w12">
        xsz warehouse
            <stock>25000</stock>
        </warehouse>

        <warehouse id = "w13">
        rza warehouse
            <stock>5000</stock>
        </warehouse>
    </stock>

</product>
```

```
<!-- defining the nutrition element for the perishable product -->

<xs:element name="nutrition">   
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="calcium" type="xs:decimal"/>
            <xs:element name="proteins" type="xs:decimal"/>
            <xs:element name="fat" type="xs:decimal"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<!-- defining the group product that is perishable -->

<xs:group name="perishableGroup">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="product">
            <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence> 
                    <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element name="manufacturer" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element name="quantity" type="xs:positiveInteger"/>
                    <xs:element name="price" type="xs:decimal"/>
                    <xs:element name="food">
                        <xs:complexType> <!-- defining the food element for perishable product -->
                            <xs:sequence>
                                <xs:element ref="nutrition"/> <!-- defined above -->
                                <xs:element name="expirationDate" type="xs:date"/>
                            </xs:sequence>
                        </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                </xs:sequence>
                <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:ID" use="required"/>
                <xs:attribute name="perishable" type="xs:string" use="required" fixed="yes"/>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:group>

<!-- defining the group product that is nonperishable -->

<xs:group name="nonperishableGroup">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="product">
            <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence> 
                    <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element name="manufacturer" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element name="quantity" type="xs:positiveInteger"/>
                    <xs:element name="price" type="xs:decimal"/>
                    <xs:element name="stock">
                        <xs:complexType>
                            <xs:sequence>
                                <xs:element name="warehouse" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                                    <xs:complexType mixed="true">
                                        <xs:sequence>
                                            <xs:element name="stock" type="xs:positiveInteger"/>
                                        </xs:sequence>
                                        <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:ID" use="required"/>
                                    </xs:complexType>
                                </xs:element>
                            </xs:sequence>
                        </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                </xs:sequence>
                <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:ID" use="required"/>
                <xs:attribute name="perishable" type="xs:string" use="required" fixed="no"/>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:group>

<xs:element name="products">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:choice minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xs:group ref="perishableGroup"/>
            <xs:group ref="nonperishableGroup"/>
        </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use attributes to control the content model of an element, with one exception: the xsi:type attribute.  The xsi:type attribute can appear in your instance document.  It tells the validating parser what type should be used to validate the element.  The type specified must be a subtype of the element's declared type (or the declared type itself).  You would then define two related types (one extends or restricts the other, or else both extend or restrict some common abstract base).  One of these types would support the case where you have a perishable item, the other one where you have a non-perishable item.

There is no way, however, to control this using the perishable attribute.  UNLESS, possibly you might do it using assertions from XSD 1.1 (I don't know).  Last I checked, XSD 1.1 was still only a draft, but if that is an option for you, you could look into it.  I believe some tools have support for it (Saxon.  Xerces?)

Comment: P.S. If you can change things, change your perishable attribute into a choice between a perishable and a non-perishable element.  That would make things easier for you, I think.

Comment: I have to validate the xml doc as is. I can't use a perishable and non-perishable, it has to be perishable. Thanks a lot though